# Алгоритм пагинации

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Пытаюсь сделать пагинацию, но очень плохо понимаю как сделать алгоритм пагинации. У меня сейчас так: статично выводится 2 начальные страницы и 2 конечные страницы, а посередине 2 страницы вперед и назад от текущей страницы. Я думаю как написать алгоритм, чтобы можно было управлять кол-во того что слева, справа и посередине.
Логика происходит в функции `logic`

```js
const per_page_max = 100; // Максимальное кол-во страниц
let current_page = 5; // Текущая страница
const btns = document.querySelector('.btns');

function appendBtn(i, ellipsis) {
  const activeBtn = current_page === i;
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.classList.add('btn');
  if (ellipsis === true) {
    button.innerHTML = '...';
    button.disabled = true;
    btns.append(button);
    return false;
  }
  if (activeBtn) {
    button.classList.add('active');
  }
  button.disabled = activeBtn;
  button.innerHTML = i;
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    current_page = i;
    btns.innerHTML = '';
    logic();
  });
  btns.append(button);
}

logic();

function logic() {

  // это лево
  appendBtn(1);
  appendBtn(2);
  // это лево

  // это середина
  if (current_page < 6) {
    appendBtn(3);
    appendBtn(4);
    appendBtn(5);
    appendBtn(6);
    appendBtn(7);
    appendBtn(current_page, true);
  } else if (current_page <= per_page_max - 5) {
    appendBtn(current_page, true);
    appendBtn(current_page - 2);
    appendBtn(current_page - 1);
    appendBtn(current_page);
    appendBtn(current_page + 1);
    appendBtn(current_page + 2);
    appendBtn(current_page, true);
  } else {
    appendBtn(current_page, true);
    appendBtn(per_page_max - 6);
    appendBtn(per_page_max - 5);
    appendBtn(per_page_max - 4);
    appendBtn(per_page_max - 3);
    appendBtn(per_page_max - 2);
  }
  // это середина

  // это право
  appendBtn(per_page_max - 1);
  appendBtn(per_page_max);
  // это право
}
```

```css
.btns>* {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #DFDFDF !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #9F9F9F !important;
  cursor: default;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
}

.btn.active {
  border: 2px solid #26a69a;
  padding: 6px 13px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #2bbbad;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну неособо понятно как быть с центральной частью, должна ли она всегда быть нечетного размера, чтобы соблюдалась симметрия. Но если да, то вот пример. Можно в принципе границы переопределить и рассчитывать по-другому.

Сейчас так:

```
logic(leftCount, centerSideCount, rightCount)
leftCount - число блоков слева
rightCount - число блоков справа
centerSideCount - число блоков по левую и правую сторону в центральной секции
```

```js
const per_page_max = 40; // Максимальное кол-во страниц
let current_page = 2; // Текущая страница
const btns = document.querySelector('.btns');

function appendBtn(i, ellipsis) {
  const activeBtn = current_page === i;
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.classList.add('btn');
  if (ellipsis === true) {
    button.innerHTML = '...';
    button.disabled = true;
    btns.append(button);
    return false;
  }
  if (activeBtn) {
    button.classList.add('active');
  }
  button.disabled = activeBtn === true ? 'disabled' : '';
  button.innerHTML = i;
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    current_page = i;
    btns.innerHTML = '';
    logic(1, 1, 3);
  });
  btns.append(button);
}

logic(1, 1, 3);

function logic(leftCount, centerSideCount, rightCount) {
  let centerLeft, centerRight;

  range(1, leftCount).forEach(appendBtn);

  centerLeft = Math.max(leftCount + 1, current_page - centerSideCount);
  centerRight = Math.min(per_page_max - rightCount, centerLeft + centerSideCount * 2);
  centerLeft = Math.max(leftCount + 1, centerRight - centerSideCount * 2);

  if (centerLeft > leftCount + 1) {
    appendBtn(current_page, true);
  }

  range(centerLeft, centerRight).forEach(appendBtn);

  if (centerRight < per_page_max - rightCount) {
    appendBtn(current_page, true);
  }

  range(per_page_max - rightCount + 1, per_page_max).forEach(appendBtn);
}

function range(start, stop) {
  if (start === undefined || stop === undefined) return [];

  const length = Math.abs(stop - start) + 1;

  return Array.from({
    length
  }, (_, i) => i * Math.sign(stop - start) + start);
}
```

```css
.btns>* {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #DFDFDF !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #9F9F9F !important;
  cursor: default;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 14px;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: background-color .3s ease-out;
}

.btn.active {
  border: 2px solid #26a69a;
  padding: 6px 13px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #2bbbad;
}
```

```html
<div class="btns"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
paginator(document.getElementById("pag"),1);

function paginator(paginContID, countElem) {
  if (paginContID) {
    if (paginContID.children.length > countElem) {
      for (let i = countElem; i < paginContID.children.length; i++) {
        paginContID.children[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
      paginContID.style.overflow = 'hidden';
      let divForPaging = document.createElement('div');
      divForPaging.className = 'divPaging';

      let bNext = document.createElement('button');
      bNext.className = 'bNextPaging';
      bNext.id = 'bNextPaging';
      bNext.innerText = String.fromCharCode(8594);

      let divContainerNumbers = document.createElement('div');
      divContainerNumbers.className = 'divContainerNumbers';

      let bPrevious = document.createElement('button');
      bPrevious.className = 'bPreviousPaging';
      bPrevious.id = 'bPreviousPaging';
      bPrevious.innerText = String.fromCharCode(8592);
      $(bPrevious).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

      divForPaging.appendChild(bPrevious);
      let countButtons = 3;
      if (Math.ceil((paginContID.children.length) / countElem) > 7) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          let bNumber = document.createElement('button');
          bNumber.className = 'bNumberPaging';
          bNumber.name = 'bNumberPaging';
          if (i == 0) {
            $(bNumber).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(bNumber).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
          }
          bNumber.innerText = i + 1;
          bNumber.value = i;
          divContainerNumbers.appendChild(bNumber);
        }
        let bNumber = document.createElement('button');
        bNumber.className = 'bNumberPaging';
        bNumber.name = 'bNumberPaging';
        bNumber.innerText = '...';
        bNumber.value = 'points';
        divContainerNumbers.appendChild(bNumber);
        let bNumberMax = document.createElement('button');
        bNumberMax.className = 'bNumberPaging';
        bNumberMax.name = 'bNumberPaging';
        bNumberMax.innerText = Math.ceil((paginContID.children.length / countElem));
        bNumberMax.value = Math.ceil((paginContID.children.length / countElem) - 1);
        divContainerNumbers.appendChild(bNumberMax);
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < Math.ceil((paginContID.children.length) / countElem); i++) {
          let bNumber = document.createElement('button');
          bNumber.className = 'bNumberPaging';
          bNumber.name = 'bNumberPaging';
          bNumber.innerText = i + 1;
          bNumber.value = i;
          if (i == 0) {
            $(bNumber).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(bNumber).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
          }
          divContainerNumbers.appendChild(bNumber);
        }
      }

      divForPaging.appendChild(divContainerNumbers);
      divForPaging.appendChild(bNext);
      paginContID.appendChild(divForPaging);

      let PageNow = 0;
      let trigOnce = 0;

      $(bNext).click(function() {
        bNextF();
      });

      function bNextF() {
        let countHide = 0;
        let countShowed = 0;
        let buttonID = $(paginContID).children().last().find("div").children();
        if (Math.ceil((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) > 7) {
          if (+PageNow >= 0 && +PageNow < 3) {
            $(buttonID[PageNow]).removeAttr('disabled');
            $(buttonID).removeClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
            $(buttonID[+PageNow + 1]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(buttonID[+PageNow + 1]).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
            trigOnce++;
          } else {
            if ((+PageNow < Math.ceil((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - 5)) {
              $(buttonID[1]).text('...');
              $(buttonID[1]).val('points');
              $(buttonID[2]).text(+PageNow + 1);
              $(buttonID[2]).val(+PageNow);
              $(buttonID[3]).text(+PageNow + 2); //;
              $(buttonID[3]).val(+PageNow + 1);
              $(buttonID[4]).text(+PageNow + 3);
              $(buttonID[4]).val(+PageNow + 2);
              $(buttonID[5]).text('...');
              $(buttonID[5]).val('points');
            } else {
              if ((+PageNow == Math.ceil((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - 5)) {
                $(buttonID[1]).text('...');
                $(buttonID[1]).val('points');
                $(buttonID[2]).text(+PageNow + 1);
                $(buttonID[2]).val(+PageNow);
                $(buttonID[3]).text(+PageNow + 2); //;
                $(buttonID[3]).val(+PageNow + 1);
                $(buttonID[4]).text(+PageNow + 3);
                $(buttonID[4]).val(+PageNow + 2);
                $(buttonID[5]).text(Math.ceil(((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) - 1));
                $(buttonID[5]).val(Math.ceil(((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) - 2));
              } else {
                $(buttonID[trigOnce]).removeAttr('disabled');
                $(buttonID).removeClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
                $(buttonID[+trigOnce + 1]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $(buttonID[+trigOnce + 1]).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
                trigOnce++;
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          $(buttonID[PageNow]).removeAttr('disabled');
          $(buttonID).removeClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
          $(buttonID[+PageNow + 1]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          $(buttonID[+PageNow + 1]).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
        }
        PageNow++;
        for (let i = 0; i < paginContID.children.length - 1; i++) {
          if ($(paginContID.children[i]).is(':visible')) {
            if (i == 0) {
              $(bPrevious).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
              'animation-name': 'fadeOutLeft'
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
                'display': 'none'
              });
            }, 600);
            countHide++;
          } else if (countHide == countElem) {
            countShowed++
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
                'display': 'flex'
              });
              $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
                'animation-name': 'fadeInRight'
              });
            }, 600)
            if (countShowed > countElem - 1) {
              if (i == paginContID.children.length - 2) {
                $(bNext).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              }
              break;
            } else if (i == paginContID.children.length - 2) {
              $(bNext).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      $(bPrevious).click(function() {
        bPreviousF();
      });

      function bPreviousF() {
        let countHide = 0;
        let countShowed = 0;
        let trigLast = 0;
        let buttonID = $(paginContID).children().last().find("div").children();
        if (Math.ceil((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) > 7) {
          if (+PageNow >= 0 && +PageNow < 4) {
            $(buttonID[PageNow]).removeAttr('disabled');
            $(buttonID).removeClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
            $(buttonID[PageNow - 1]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $(buttonID[PageNow - 1]).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
            trigOnce--;
          } else {
            if ((+PageNow < Math.ceil((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - 4) && +PageNow > 4) {
              $(buttonID[1]).text('...');
              $(buttonID[1]).val('points');
              $(buttonID[2]).text(+PageNow - 1);
              $(buttonID[2]).val(+PageNow - 2);
              $(buttonID[3]).text(+PageNow); //;
              $(buttonID[3]).val(+PageNow - 1);
              $(buttonID[4]).text(+PageNow + 1);
              $(buttonID[4]).val(+PageNow);
              $(buttonID[5]).text('...');
              $(buttonID[5]).val('points');
            } else if ((+PageNow >= Math.ceil((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - 4)) {
              if ((+PageNow == Math.ceil((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - 4)) {
                $(buttonID[1]).text('...');
                $(buttonID[1]).val('points');
                $(buttonID[2]).text(+PageNow - 1);
                $(buttonID[2]).val(+PageNow - 2);
                $(buttonID[3]).text(+PageNow); //;
                $(buttonID[3]).val(+PageNow - 1);
                $(buttonID[4]).text(+PageNow + 1);
                $(buttonID[4]).val(+PageNow);
                $(buttonID[5]).text('...');
                $(buttonID[5]).val('points');
              } else {;
                $(buttonID[trigOnce]).removeAttr('disabled');
                $(buttonID).removeClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
                $(buttonID[trigOnce - 1]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $(buttonID[trigOnce - 1]).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
                trigOnce--;
              }
            } else if (+PageNow == 4) {
              $(buttonID[1]).text('2');
              $(buttonID[1]).val('1');
              $(buttonID[2]).text(+PageNow - 1);
              $(buttonID[2]).val(+PageNow - 2);
              $(buttonID[3]).text(+PageNow); //;
              $(buttonID[3]).val(+PageNow - 1);
              $(buttonID[4]).text(+PageNow + 1);
              $(buttonID[4]).val(+PageNow);
              $(buttonID[5]).text('...');
              $(buttonID[5]).val('points');
            }
          }
        } else {
          $(buttonID[PageNow]).removeAttr('disabled');
          $(buttonID).removeClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
          $(buttonID[PageNow - 1]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          $(buttonID[PageNow - 1]).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
        }
        PageNow--;
        for (let i = paginContID.children.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
          if ($(paginContID.children[i]).is(':visible')) {
            if (i == paginContID.children.length - 2) {
              $(bNext).removeAttr('disabled');
              trigLast = 1
            }
            $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
              'animation-name': 'fadeOutRight'
            });
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
                'display': 'none'
              });
            }, 600);
            countHide++;
          } else if (countHide == countElem || (trigLast)) {
            countShowed++
            setTimeout(function() {
              $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
                'display': 'flex'
              });
              $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
                'animation-name': 'fadeInLeft'
              });
            }, 600)
            if (countShowed > countElem - 1) {
              if (i == 0) {
                $(bPrevious).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                if (buttonID[0]) {
                  buttonID[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
              }
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      $('[name="bNumberPaging"]').click(function() {
        let oneMoreTrigger = 0;
        let buttonID = $(paginContID).children().last().find("div").children();
        if (this.value != 'points') {
          if ((Math.ceil((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) > 7) && (+PageNow <= Math.ceil((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - 4) && +PageNow > 3 && (this.value != Math.ceil((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - 1) && this.value != 0) {
            trigOnce = 3;
            if (PageNow < this.value) {
              bNextF();
            } else if (PageNow >= this.value) {
              bPreviousF();
            }
          } else {
            PageNow = this.value;
            $(buttonID).removeAttr('disabled');
            $(buttonID).removeClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
            if ((Math.ceil((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) > 7)) {
              if (PageNow >= this.value) {
                if (this.value == Math.ceil(((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - 5)) {
                  oneMoreTrigger = 1;
                  $(buttonID[3]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                  $(buttonID[3]).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
                }
              }
              if (PageNow <= this.value && (Math.ceil((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) > 7)) {
                if (this.value == 4) {
                  oneMoreTrigger = 1;
                  $(buttonID[3]).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                  $(buttonID[3]).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
                }
              }
            }
            if (oneMoreTrigger == 0) {
              $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              $(this).addClass('bNumberPagingSelected');
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < paginContID.children.length - 1; i++) {
              if ($(paginContID.children[i]).is(':visible')) {
                if (i != paginContID.children.length - 2) {
                  $(bNext).removeAttr('disabled');
                }
                if (i != 0) {
                  $(bPrevious).removeAttr('disabled');
                }
                $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
                  'animation-name': 'fadeOut'
                });
                setTimeout(function() {
                  $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
                    'display': 'none'
                  });
                }, 600);
              }
            }
            for (let i = PageNow * countElem; i < PageNow * countElem + countElem; i++) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
                  'display': 'flex'
                });
                $(paginContID.children[i]).css({
                  'animation-name': 'fadeIn'
                });
              }, 600)
              if (i == 0) {
                $(bPrevious).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              } else if (i == paginContID.children.length - 2) {
                $(bNext).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              }
              if ((Math.ceil((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) > 7)) {
                if (PageNow < 4) {
                  trigOnce = PageNow
                }
                if (PageNow <= Math.ceil((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) && PageNow >= Math.ceil((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - 2) {
                  trigOnce = 7 - (Math.ceil((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - PageNow);
                }

                if (PageNow == 4) {
                  $(buttonID[1]).text('...');
                  $(buttonID[1]).val('points');
                  $(buttonID[2]).text(+PageNow);
                  $(buttonID[2]).val(+PageNow - 1);
                  $(buttonID[3]).text(+PageNow + 1); //;
                  $(buttonID[3]).val(+PageNow);
                  $(buttonID[4]).text(+PageNow + 2);
                  $(buttonID[4]).val(+PageNow + 1);
                  $(buttonID[5]).text('...');
                  $(buttonID[5]).val('points');
                }

                if (PageNow == Math.ceil(((+paginContID.children.length - 1) / +countElem) - 5)) {
                  $(buttonID[1]).text('...');
                  $(buttonID[1]).val('points');
                  $(buttonID[2]).text(+PageNow);
                  $(buttonID[2]).val(+PageNow - 1);
                  $(buttonID[3]).text(+PageNow + 1); //;
                  $(buttonID[3]).val(+PageNow);
                  $(buttonID[4]).text(+PageNow + 2);
                  $(buttonID[4]).val(+PageNow + 1);
                  $(buttonID[5]).text('...');
                  $(buttonID[5]).val('points');
                  trigOnce = 3;
                }
                if (i == 0) {
                  $(bPrevious).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                  $(buttonID[1]).text('2');
                  $(buttonID[1]).val('1');
                  $(buttonID[2]).text(3);
                  $(buttonID[2]).val(2);
                  $(buttonID[3]).text(4); //;
                  $(buttonID[3]).val(3);
                  $(buttonID[4]).text(5);
                  $(buttonID[4]).val(4);
                  $(buttonID[5]).text('...');
                  $(buttonID[5]).val('points');
                }
                if (i == paginContID.children.length - 2) {
                  $(bNext).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                  $(buttonID[1]).text('...');
                  $(buttonID[1]).val('points');
                  $(buttonID[2]).text(Math.ceil(((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) - 4));
                  $(buttonID[2]).val(Math.ceil(((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) - 5));
                  $(buttonID[3]).text(Math.ceil(((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) - 3));
                  $(buttonID[3]).val(Math.ceil(((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) - 4));
                  $(buttonID[4]).text(Math.ceil(((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) - 2));
                  $(buttonID[4]).val(Math.ceil(((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) - 3));
                  $(buttonID[5]).text(Math.ceil(((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) - 1));
                  $(buttonID[5]).val(Math.ceil(((paginContID.children.length - 1) / countElem) - 2));
                }

              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.divPaging {
    width: calc(100% - 2vh);
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #f4f2fb;
    color: #a5d774;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 1vh 1vh;
}

.divContainerNumbers{
    width: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    height: fit-content;
}

.bPreviousPaging,.bNextPaging,.bNumberPaging{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    padding: 1.5vh;
    color: #a5d774;
    background: #0F2522;
}

.bPreviousPaging,.bNextPaging,.bNumberPaging{
    width: fit-content;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.bNumberPaging{
    margin: 0 1px;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.bNumberPagingSelected{
    background: #a5d774;
    color: #0F2522;
}

.bNextPaging{
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.bPreviousPaging:hover,.bNextPaging:hover,.bNumberPaging:hover{
    background: #a5d774;
    color: #0F2522;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bNextPaging:disabled, .bPreviousPaging:disabled{
    background: #B8BBC8;
    color: #0F2522;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

#pag{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pag{
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 485px){
    .bPreviousPaging,.bNextPaging,.bNumberPaging{
        padding: 1vh;
        line-height: 14px;
        font-size: 12px;
        flex: 1;
    }
    .divContainerNumbers{
        flex: 1;
    }
    .bNumberPaging{
        margin: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 370px){
    .bPreviousPaging,.bNextPaging,.bNumberPaging{
        padding: 1vh 0.6vh;
        line-height: 14px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://vivify.mkcreative.cz/assets/css/vivify.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pag">
<div class="vivify pag">
1
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
2
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
3
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
4
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
5
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
6
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
7
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
8
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
9
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
10
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
11
</div>
<div class="vivify pag">
12
</div>
</div>
```

Вот, недавно писал, вроде бы рабочий.

---

Объявляется следующим образом: 1 элемент - родитель содержащий множество элементов, 2 элемент - количество отображаемых элементов на текущей странице.

```
paginator(document.getElementById('notificationBlock'),2);
```

Для того, что бы были анимации прокрутки и прочего, требуется подключить библиотеку [vivify](http://www.vivify.mkcreative.cz/) и каждому дочернему элементу прописать дополнительный класс - "vivify"

---

И вот соответственно css - меняйте его как душе угодно, если будут вопросы - пишите.

Comment: Однако, многовато столбиков "ручного" кода, когда это всё можно было бы сократить раза в 3-4, используя циклы или функции...

Comment: Там ручной код используется только для скрытия кнопок пагинации. То есть у нас задано максимальное количество отображаемых кнопок условно 7,и если кнопок больше, то появляется многоточие на месте кнопки. Сделано так дабы умещалось в экран.

Comment: @Kirzzz если не сложно, отредактируйте ответ, чтобы можно было запустить здесь (как в моём ответе)

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Отредактировал, только анимаций каких-либо нет, так как не удалось найти ссылку на vivify внешнюю. В пагинации есть косяки некоторые - не в логике. Например если быстро тыкать по кнопкам, то есть шанс, что все слетит, для этого в строках, где происходит исчезновение им надо задавать свойство disabled.